# How to monitor multiple processes and start new one if one is exited?

Tags: python, node.js, ipc, pm2, process-monitoring

I want to run a python script as a daemon with some arguments as different processes and monitor them continuously. If any of them exits, whether gracefully or with error, I want to start new process using new arguments.

I thought to use pm2 and its nodejs api for this, but I couldn't find any useful information on how to use pm2 api to monitor process messages.

Any ideas how to accomplish it?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with [Supervisor](http://supervisord.org/index.html), which is a Process Control System that offers an extensive range of options for you to describe the expected behavior.